# javascript module pattern works on jsbin but not in my server/browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, scope, module-pattern

I am a backend developer, I write javascript only when needed and in not the best ways. But I wanted to redeem myself and star writing organized and following best practices as much as I could.

So I started a module pattern to encapsulate some functions and bind UI events from my markup, becuase this was pretty much try and error, I used jsbin following the suggestion of a friend who is a front end developer.

The thing is, that my concept works on jsbin, but then I moved that to my js file in the server and there it seems I loose scope of the jQuery objects that I cache inside my module pattern.

http://jsbin.com/ciwomeve/7/edit

The functionality is pretty basic I populate the options of two select elements (this works) then I bind the on change events for those selects, and when triggered I should call some functions that eventually should do an ajax request to my backend and obtain data.

Can you guys please advise me on the code, and tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: Is jQuery linked on the pages your server is sending? Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: Is behind a VPN, so sadly no, but yeah I have jq <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> the populateHostLists fn uses jQuery and that one does work

Comment: Some thoughts: if you're just viewing an HTML page in your browser (i.e. file not being served, URL reads 'file://'), then the protocol-relative path to jQuery won't work. I know you said you're serving them, but I thought I'd mention it just in case. Or you might have the order of your script tags wrong.

Comment: Or if your scripts are in the head, they might be trying to access stuff that hasn't loaded. You could try moving your scripts to just before </body>, or wrap them in a $().ready

Comment: I get what you're saying, yes is actually being served thru apache, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much to go on here, but I'm fairly certain that your issue is that your script tag is in `<head>`, and it's running before your content is loaded. If this is the case, it will be trying to access elements in the DOM that don't yet exist (e.g. when this line runs, `$hostSelect1: $('#host-select-1')` the select element with id `host-select-1` won't exist yet, but jQuery will look for it anyway and fail silently).

You can move your script to the bottom of the page, right before `</body>`, in which case you can be certain that all of your content will be loaded when your script runs. This method also has some other performance benefits. Or else you can wrap your call to `DbDiff.init()` in `$().ready`, like this `$().ready(function(){DbDiff.init()});`, which will have largely the same effect (except that `settings` has already been evaluated... you would need to do a little restructuring in order to make sure `$('#host-select-1')`, etc. are evaluated and assigned to `$hostSelect1` only after your DOM content has loaded).